# Creating and saving Excel document From VBA in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to be able to run a macro in a Word document that will create an Excel document and then save that spreadsheet in a shared folder.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Sub Monthly_Commission_Extract()

Dim objExcel
Dim objDoc
Dim objSelection
Dim SaveAs1 As String
SaveAs1 = ("\\stnlinasshd01\P403759\Month End\Monthly Commission Extract\1st Save")

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objDoc = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

objExcel.Visible = True

Set objSelection = objExcel.Selection

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=SaveAs1, FileFormat:=-4158, CreateBackup:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The code is giving me an error:

> Run-time error '424': Object required

At the following piece of code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=SaveAs1, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
```

Please advise how I get around this.

Comment: change `FileFormat:=xlText` to `FileFormat:=-4158` since Word know nothing about excel constants (untill you add reference to Excel object library) and also change `Dim SaveAs As String` to `Dim SaveAs1 As String`

Comment: I did as you suggested but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: `Below is the ameneded code:` - where?

Comment: I have amended the original code above.

Comment: I'm ia a similar situation, but I want the user to be able to choose where to save the escel file. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
```

not just

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs
```

Anything which "belongs" to Excel must be prefixed with your `objExcel` application reference.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple and straight forward code that creates a new excel workbook and saves it into a path on your local disk. This VBA code has ben tested from inside MS Word.

```
Private Sub CreateExcel()

Dim myExcel As Object
Dim myWb As Object

Set myExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWb = myExcel.Workbooks.Add

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

myWb.SaveAs FileName:="D:\test\dump.xls"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

myWb.Close False
Set myWb = Nothing
myExcel.Quit
Set myExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

In your case, the following would have worked because 'objDoc' is derived from the excel object reference.

```
objDoc.SaveAs FileName:=SaveAs1, FileFormat:=-4158, CreateBackup:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh captain, yes my captain,
the errormessage says clearly that a object is missed, I think this line
SaveAs1 = ("\stnlinasshd01\P403759\Month End\Monthly Commission Extract\1st Save")
is the problem You should a SET-Statement out of this, by starting this line with "SET ", then you have the object required.